# Ubiquitous "apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed" error with default Apache and Homebrew PHP 7.0 on Sierra

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm trying to get simple Apache and PHP 7.0 set up with Homebrew on Mac Sierra using the default Apache and Homebrew PHP (php70 formula), and I'm getting the ubiquitous errors:

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for myMachineName
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I've been reading many posts on this error, and everything that has been suggested is not working. Here are the details on what I have set up:

In httpd.conf:

- `DocumentRoot` set to `~/Sites` directory (`/Users/myUserName/Sites`)
- `<Directory /Users/myUserName/Sites>`
- `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.23_15/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`
- `ServerName localhost:80`

I installed PHP with `brew install php70 --with-apache`, so the `/libexec` directory (and therefore `libphp70.so`) are there.

In hosts:

- `127.0.0.1 localhost`

I have also verified that I am editing the appropriate `httpd.conf` file with the following two commands:

```
whereis httpd (/usr/sbin/httpd)
/usr/sbin/httpd -V
```

If I run `apachectl configtest`, it returns `Syntax OK` after the two main errors, so there aren't any errors in `httpd.conf`.

When I go to http://localhost, I get the `index.php` (and `index.html`) from that directory. However, if I go to http://localhost/phpinfo.php (`phpinfo.php` is in `~/Sites`) it just shows the code, not the output.

From what I can tell, I have everything set up properly. Why would I still be getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a stray httpd.conf. I had been trying to use Homebrew's httpd, and wasn't having any luck, so I had fallen back to the default Apache. When I looked at the path to the config file, I didn't notice that was reading from /usr/local/. Once I cleaned up files and made sure the correct conf file was being read, the error went away.